# Can't read keyboard input

Tags: c#, xna

```
KeyboardState kbstate = Keyboard.GetState();
Keys[] pressed = kbstate.GetPressedKeys();
```

<kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Numlock</kbd><kbd>Home</kbd><kbd>Ins</kbd> and possibly more worked fine but when I press any letter, number, or arrows, it won't read it.

Comment: according to the documentation you should get all the keys. have you checked what *is* in the array using the debugger?

Comment: i even tried a brand new project it must be something else
(it's not the keyboard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only ever seen keyboard input handled like so:

```
KeyboardState kbState = Keyboard.GetState();

if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
{
    // 'A' key is down
}
```

If you wanted key pressed (i.e. the button was *just* pressed) you would use the following method:

```
public bool IsNewKeyPress(Keys key)
{
    return (kbState.IsKeyDown(key) &&
         oldKbState.IsKeyUp(key));
}

// And in the update method...
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    oldKbState = kbState;
    kbState = Keyboard.GetState();

    if (IsNewKeyPress(Keys.A))
    {
        // A was *just* pressed
    }

    // ...
}
```